# Rename a Graph Vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

We have VertexAdd, VertexDelete, EdgeAdd, EdgeDelete but no VertexRename.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I fiddled around with AnnotationValue,AnnotationKeys,IndicedenceList etc to
create a new Vertex, attach all edges like the original vertex and after all the housekeeping is done (and migrate all edge info and vertex info like Weights etc) delete the original.
However with styling this is not always working so I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing other than recreating a whole new Graph and change the Vertex name from the source it came from.
I'm working on a small Graph creating tool and when I make a mistake with the name of a Vertex I'm in "trouble'. A rename might come in handy. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`VertexReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html):

```
VertexReplace[CycleGraph[4, VertexLabels -> "Name"], {1 -> "foo", 3 -> "bar"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Omg... How did I miss that... Very sad and happy at the same time..